# GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY after a call to glDrawArrays. Why?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I have a situation that seems rather strange. I will try to provide enough details, so that someone smarter than me can explain this. Basically here is the setup:

```
OS: Android 2.2 Froyo
Device: SGS Vibrant
Application: OpenGL-ES 1.1
```

And here is the problem: I can successfully render a fairly complex scene, and it can run endlessly for hours without leaking any memory. Dalvikvm shows up in the logcat once every 3-5 minutes and there would have been no problem unless I try to exit my application and run it again. In fact I can restart my application 2 times, but on the third time, I get `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY`.

I have tracked the error down to the `gl.glDrawArrays()` call. I can confirm that the `gl.glGetError()` returns 0 prior to the DrawArrays call in question, and it will return 1285 (GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY) after the DrawArrays call.

Naturally, I have thought that I am not cleaning up the resources and releasing OpenGL context. Here is what I do when the application is being shut down.

```
for(int x=0; x<buffers.length; x++){
   if(gl.glIsBuffer(buffers[x])){
      gl.glDeleteBuffers(1, buffers, x);
      buffers[x]=0;
   }
}
for(int y=0; y<textures.length; y++){
   if(gl.glIsTexture(textures[y])){
      gl.glDeleteTextures(1, textures, y);
      textures[y]=0;
   }
}
System.out.println("ERROR: "+gl.glGetError());
finish();
```

When I run my application the first two times, I do not get any error returned at shutdown. However on the 3rd try, I get the aforementioned error, which I tracked down to the `gl.glDrawArrays()` call.

Here is a brief summary of what happens during the 3rd run:

1. Objects 1-56 go through their respective `gl.glDrawArrays()` calls like hot knives through butter. No errors generated.
2. Objects 57-64 generate a `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` error. The objects get rendered, but the texture is black.

I am more than sure that I am deleting all of the Buffers and Textures at app shutdown. I am also confident that this error is not specific to one 3D model, as I have tried skipping model #57, but then #58 will still get this error.

Please help, as I am running out of ideas!

Answer (score 8):

I just found out GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY can be set if you first pass the NULL pointer to glVertexAttribPointer.

No error before drawArrays, GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY after. (tested on Galaxy S2 4.1.2, GLES2) Maybe that's what's going on for some reason after a while in your program?

this took me forever to find... TODO: more unit tests :)

Answer (score 2):

> GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY after a call to glDrawArrays. Why?

It is really hard to say but from what I have learned, this error occurs when you are having *too* many polygons in memory, or at least, same vertices are being defined *n* times. Since you said you're having a complex scene; this problem is *probably* a memory problem.

One solution *could* be to use `glDrawElements()` and let your scene reduce the amount of vertices by letting your polygons share same vertices when necessary. In this way your memory is lowered and it is *possible* that this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found that `glDrawArrays()` was setting `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` when `glVertexAttribPointer()` was being called with a non-null pointer. This turned out to be because a different bit of code had called `glBindBuffer()` to use a vertex array object but then hadn't unbound the buffer afterwards. A call to `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can also happen if you have incorrect glVertexAttribPointer calls on Android. I got this error , when I incorrectly passed ST attributes to a previously prepared normal attribute (duplicate glVertexAttribPointer calls to prepare the normal attribute, the second should have bound to the ST attribute).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` error was also thrown after `glDrawArrays`, because my framebuffer had an attachment texture that didn't have any memory allocated on GPU (in particular I called `glTexStorage2D` with `levels` equal to 0).

My setup is mobile:

- OpenGL ES 3.2
- Qualcomm Snapdragon 888
- Harmony OS v4.0